# obtener el mayor puntaje de un juego

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de obtener el mejor puntaje de dos juegos que juegan dos personas diferentes por juego, de momento obtuve los juego ordenado alfabeticmante, adjunto codigo.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define JUEGO 2
#define JUGADORES 2

struct JUEGOS{
    char juego[50];
    char player[50];
    int puntaje[10];
};

// Parametros
void ordenarJuegos(struct JUEGOS game[], int );
void mejorPuntajeJuegos(struct JUEGOS game[], int);


int main(){

struct JUEGOS game[JUEGO];

int i,j;

for(i = 0; i < JUEGO; i++){
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n\t Nombre del juego: ");
    gets(game[i].juego);
    
    for(j = 0; j < JUGADORES; j++){
        
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n\t Nombre del Jugador: ");
        gets(game[j].player);
    
        printf("\n\t Puntacion: ");
        scanf("%d", &game[j].puntaje);
        printf("\n\t -----");
    }
}

printf("\n\n -----------PUNTO 1-----------");
printf("\n\t Juegos ordenados alfabeticamente");
ordenarJuegos(game, JUEGO);


printf("\n\n -----------PUNTO 2-----------");
printf("\n\t Mejor jugador");
mejorPuntajeJuegos(game, JUGADORES);

return 0;
}
```

En esta funcion lo que hago es el ordenamiento alfabeticamente de los juegos ingresados

```
void ordenarJuegos(struct JUEGOS game[], int N){
int i,j,x;

struct JUEGOS aux;

for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < N - 1 - i; j++){
        if(strcmp(game[j].juego, game[j+1].juego) > 0){
            aux = game[j];
            game[j] = game[j+1];
            game[j+1] = aux;
        }
    }
}

    for(x = 0; x < N; x++){
        printf("\n\t %s", game[x].juego);
    }
}
```

aca esta la funcion con la que tengo problemas al obtener el mayor puntaje, se me ocurrio hacer que el programa calcule el mejor jugador de cada juego por separado pero la verdad que no se me ocurre como hacerlo, espero que me puedan dar una mano, muchas gracias!!!

```
void mejorPuntajeJuegos(struct JUEGOS game[], int N){

int i, j,x, aux1 = 0;
struct JUEGOS aux;

for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < N - 1 - i; j++){
        if(game[j].puntaje > game[j+1].puntaje){
            aux = game[j];
            game[j] = game[j+1];
            game[j+1] = aux;
        }
    }
}

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("\n\t Mejores: %s", game[i].player);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error de lógica entre tus declaraciones y tu bucle en `main()`.

Las declaraciones apuntan a varias (hasta JUEGO=2) instancias, cada una con 1 (uno) "juego" (un nombre con hasta 49 letras), 1 (un) "player" (un nombre con hasta 49 letras), y hasta 10 "puntajes".

El código apunta a JUEGO=2 instancias, cada una con su nombre guardado en `game[i].juego`. Luego cada "juego" puede tener hasta JUGADOR=2 "jugadores", cuyo nombre se guarda en `game[j].player`; es decir, a cada juego el nombre del "player" machaca lo que había antes. Y para cada "player" hay 1 (solo un) "punctuaje", que también machaca los anteriores, guardado en `game[j].puntaje[0]` (cuya dirección es la misma que `game[j].puntaje`; hay un error de tipo en la llamada a `scanf()`).

Answer (score 0):

El array que tienes definido en tu programa no tiene demasiado sentido porque solo puedes almacenar el nombre de un jugador en cada juego.

Así, en el siguiente fragmento:

```
for(i = 0; i < JUEGO; i++){
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n\t Nombre del juego: ");
    gets(game[i].juego);
    
    for(j = 0; j < JUGADORES; j++){
        
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n\t Nombre del Jugador: ");
        gets(game[j].player);                // <<---
    
        printf("\n\t Puntacion: ");
        scanf("%d", &game[j].puntaje);       // <<---
        printf("\n\t -----");
    }
}
```

Fíjate en los comentarios, esas líneas están machacando información anterior:

```
i=0
    j=0 -> gets(game[0].player); <--+
    j=1 -> gets(game[1].player); <--|-+
i=1                                 | |
    j=0 -> gets(game[0].player); <--+ |
    j=1 -> gets(game[1].player); <----+
```

La puntuación debería ir siempre de la mano del nombre del jugador que la ha logrado:

```
#define MAX_PARTIDAS 10
#define MAX_JUEGOS 2

struct PARTIDA
{
    char player[50];
    int puntaje;
};

struct JUEGO
{
    char nombre[50];
    struct PARTIDA resultados[MAX_PARTIDAS];
};

struct JUEGO game[MAX_JUEGOS];
```

Esta estructura ahora es capaz de almacenar 20 resultados, 10 para cada juego.